# sql - multiple values from two columns from different tables and put the result in second column of the second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables, one with ''product''(id_product,id_company,product_name,description,price) and a table ''order'' (id_order,id_client,id_product,product_quantity) and I would like to multiply product.price with order.product_quantity and put out the result in a new column in the ''order'' table, preferably a computed column

thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you want to put it in as a 'computed' column? To whichever application you need the multiplied result, you can just do a join and get it.

Answer (score 0):

join them using id_product

```
SELECT p.price * o.product_quantity newcolumn
  FROM product p
  JOIN order o
    ON p.id_product = o.id_product
```